# OCaml lex: doesn't work at all, whatsoever

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex

I am at the end of my rope here. I cannot get anything to work in ocamllex, and it is driving me nuts. This is my `.mll` file:

```
{

open Parser

}

rule next = parse
  | (['a'-'z'] ['a'-'z']*) as id { Identifier id }
  | '=' { EqualsSign }
  | ';' { Semicolon }
  | '\n' | ' ' { next lexbuf }
  | eof { EOF }
```

Here are the contents of the file I pass in as input:

```
a=b;
```

Yet, when I compile and run the thing, I get an error on the very first character, saying it's not valid. I honestly have no idea what's going on, and Google has not helped me at all. How can this even be possible? As you can see, I'm really stumped here.

EDIT:

I was working for so long that I gave up on the parser. Now this is the relevant code in my main file:

```
let parse_file filename =
  let l = Lexing.from_channel (open_in filename) in
    try
      Lexer.next l; ()
    with
      | Failure msg ->
        printf "line: %d, col: %d\n" l.lex_curr_p.pos_lnum l.lex_curr_p.pos_cnum
```

Prints out "line: 1, col: 1".

Comment: Could you provide the ML file where you defined the constructors like Identifier? Also, could you confirm that ocamllex and ocamlc didn't complaint at compile time?

Comment: They were defined in parser.mly as standard, and neither complain.

Comment: @marsolk: I'm curious - did you ever figure this out? What was the problem?

Answer (score 10):

Without the corresponding ocamlyacc parser, nobody will be able to find the issue with your code since your lexer works perfectly fine!

I have taken the liberty of writing the following tiny parser (parser.mly) that constructs a list of identifier pairs, e.g. input "a=b;" should give the singleton list [("a", "b")].

```
%{%}

%token <string> Identifier
%token EqualsSign
%token Semicolon
%token EOF

%start start
%type <(string * string) list> start

%%

start:
| EOF {[]}
| Identifier EqualsSign Identifier Semicolon start {($1, $3) :: $5}
;

%%
```

To test whether the parser does what I promised, we create another file (main.ml) that parses the string "a=b;" and prints the result.

```
let print_list = List.iter (fun (a, b) -> Printf.printf "%s = %s;\n" a b)
let () = print_list (Parser.start Lexer.next (Lexing.from_string "a=b;"))
```

The code should compile (e.g. ocamlbuild main.byte) without any complaints and the program should output "a=b;" as promised.

---

In response to the latest edit:

In general, I don't believe that catching standard library exceptions that are meant to indicate failure or misuse (like Invalid_argument or Failure) is a good idea. The reason is that they are used ubiquitously throughout the library such that you usually cannot tell which function raised the exception and why it did so.

Furthermore, you are throwing away the only useful information: the error message! The error message should tell you what the source of the problem is (my best guess is an IO-related issue). Thus, you should either print the error message or let the exception propagate to the toplevel. Personally, I prefer the latter option.

However, you probably still want to deal with syntactically ill-formed inputs in a graceful manner. For this, you can define a new exception in the lexer and add a default case that catches invalid tokens.

```
{
  exception Unexpected_token
}
...
| _ {raise Unexpected_token}
```

Now, you can catch the newly defined exception in your main file and, unlike before, the exception is specific to syntactically invalid inputs. Consequently, you know both the source and the cause of the exception giving you the chance to do something far more meaningful than before.

A fairly random OCaml development hint: If you compile the program with debug information enabled, setting the environment variable [OCAMLRUNPARAM](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual024.html#toc96) to "b" (e.g. export OCAMLRUNPARAM=b) enables stack traces for uncaught exceptions!

Comment: I suppose I should've mentioned that after trying for so long, I'm now just testing it without the parser, and it still gives me this error. I'll edit the post with code from my main file.

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't; in this case, I was getting `Failure("lexing: empty token")`, which I looked up to find it meant it saw a character that didn't correspond to anything in the lexer. Eventually, I put in another rule: `| _ as c { Printf.printf "Unrecognized character: %c\n" c; raise (Failure "") }`
, and now it prints "Unrecognized character: a". However, I will try with the debugging information to see what's going on.

Answer (score 7):

btw. ocamllex also can do the `+` operator for 'one or more' in regular expressions, so this

```
['a'-'z']+
```

is equivalent to your

```
['a'-'z']['a'-'z']*
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just struggling with the same thing (which is how I found this question), only to finally realize that I had mistakenly specified the path to input file as `Sys.argv.(0)` instead of `Sys.argv.(1)`! LOLs

I really hope it helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have a space in the regular expression for identifiers. This could keep the lexer from recognizing a=b, although it should still recognize a = b ;